# How to send a message to a TThread from main thread in Delphi?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I want to send a message to a thread and handle it in the thread. How can I do this in Delphi? I guess `PostMessage` is the way to go, but the examples I've seen so far are describing the other way, i.e. from the thread to main thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I won't even try and explain or write any code. Just look at this tutorial. It's a little old, but very good imho.
[Multithreading - The Delphi Way](http://web.archive.org/web/20120423060358/http://www.eonclash.com/Tutorials/Multithreading/MartinHarvey1.1/ToC.html)

Comment: Thank you. Even codegear's own site has links to a wrong (former) address.

Comment: I think I've just found it in http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/14809 and in http://thaddy.co.uk/threads/. What specific part talk about messages?

Comment: Although the link is found, it is missing images

Answer (score 6):

You can either have a message loop (possibly with a hidden notification window) in your thread and send a Windows message to it, or you can use a more native (less-GUI) way of doing it, such as a queue protected by a critical section combined with a manual-reset event that the thread waits on and the sending thread signals.

A more general solution is a producer-consumer queue, which in the classic implementation uses a couple of semaphores to keep track of consumers and producers and a third semaphore for mutually exclusive access to the queue; however, more optimal producer-consumer queues are available on the net.

Comment: And remember, kids: DO NOT use .Synchronize() if performance is your goal :)

Comment: Could not agree more. If that was an answer instead of a comment I would have voted it up.
For a nice little rant about the dos and donts of TThread see also http://newsgroups.cryer.info/borland/public.delphi.internet.winsock/200507/0507273541.html

Answer (score 3):

Why would you need to do it?  It is only for one reason that I ever had to create a message loop in a secondary thread, and that is because the thread used COM objects.  The calls to *OleInitialize()* and *OleUnitialize()* are a sign that you **need** a standard *GetMessage()* loop.  In that case it's also necessary to just post messages to that thread, using *PostThreadMessage()*, because normal blocking synchronization calls would interfere with the message loop.  Otherwise, just don't do it.

If you are at Delphi 2007 or 2009, be sure to look into [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/) by Primož Gabrijelčič, it should make your job much easier.

Comment: Why would you need to do it? For example, i have a thread thats polling events from a server in every 1000msec but i need to change the polling rate to 5000msec. Stopping then starting the thread again for this purpose is too much.

Comment: @tdiop: To achieve this no message needs to be sent to the thread, there are many other, better ways to do it. Check the other answers for inspiration.