# Multithread interactions

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Main Form:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    class var counter : Integer;
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit4, Unit5;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  th1 : thCounter;
  th2 : thPrinter;
begin
  th1:= thCounter.Create;
  th2:= thPrinter.Create;
end;

end.
```

Thread Counter :

```
unit Unit4;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, Unit3;

type
  thCounter = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation

{ thCounter }

procedure thCounter.Execute;
var
  i: Integer;
  printVal : Integer;
begin
  { Place thread code here }
  printVal:= 50;
  for i := 0 to 1000000000 do
  begin
    Form3.counter:= i;
    if Form3.counter = printVal then
    begin
      // RUN print thread    ????
      printVal:= printVal + 50;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Thread Print :

```
unit Unit5;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, Unit3;

type
  thPrinter = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure printIt;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils;

{ thPrinter }

procedure thPrinter.Execute;
begin
  { Place thread code here }
  Synchronize(printIt);
end;

procedure thPrinter.printIt;
begin
  Form3.Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Form3.counter));
end;

end.
```

I am workin on simple project. But i stuck.

I have 2 thread which are thCounter and thPrint.
My thCounter, increase the Counter to 1 billion. And i want to call another thread ( thPrint ) when the counter 50 and multiples like 100, 150, 200 to print the screen in TMemo....

How can i send a message to thPrint from thCounter?

Comment: have you looked at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438945/cross-thread-communication-in-delphi

Comment: i didnt. Thanks, ill check :)

Comment: @Ken ok but that is not my question :/

Comment: @Ken accessing a data member of a class is just fine, no VCL/threading issues there. The design is dubious, but the issue you point out does not apply here.

Comment: @Heart the issue is not read vs write. The issue is threead affinity of windows, thread safety of all access (read and write), and thread safety of MakeObjectInstance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To signal the other thread, use a synchronization primitive, like a [TSimpleEvent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TSimpleEvent_Methods).

Let it be owned by the `thCounter` thread, and pass a reference to it when `thPrinter` is created.

In the `thPrinter.Execute`:

```
while not Terminated do
begin
  if waitEvent.WaitFor(100) = wrSignaled then // Keep it listening to the Terminated flag
  begin
    Synchronize(PrintIt);
  end;
end;
```

And in the `thCounter`:

```
waitEvent.SetEvent;  // Triggers the printIt
```

Just create the waitEvent so that it automatically is reset after the event has been triggered.

```
waitEvent := TSimpleEvent.Create(nil, false,false,'');
```